# Restrict access to page to only guest visitors ie prevent logged-in users to access a page (Rails 4, devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I have a question a little weird: I'd like to restrict the access to a page to only NON  logged-in users.

Should I do this like this:

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def globalpresence 
    redirect_to root_path if user_signed_in?
  end

end
```

Is the right way to do this ?
Is there a cleaner/more proper way to that with Rails or devise?

Thanks

Comment: That doesn't look too bad but I would change the name to `check_global_presence` (more readable and states what it does) and add a `before_action :check_global_presence`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A before filter would probably be more flexible in the long run

```
before_filter :only_allow_guest_users, only: :global presence

def globalpresence
end

def only_allow_guest_users
  redirect_to root_path if user_signed_in?
end
```

Comment: Or maybe if current_user? but I think the user_signed_in? reads better

Comment: thanks. i just think you made an error in the code it's before_filter: and not plain before:

Comment: @Mathieu definitely, good catch! In Rails 4.1+ it would be before_action so 2x wrong on my part!